# JSF/XHTML - one xhtml page which includes the same xhtml page twice

Tags: java, html, jsf, xhtml

I got a xhtml page with a sessionscoped bean. Now I want to use this page twice in another html page, one on the left side and 1 on the right side of the screen. If I include it, it refers to the same bean, how can i make them independent, without writing the html with a different bean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tags to apply this concept. You can create your own tags and add them in your xhtml page taglib

```
            <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
                xmlns:taglibname="http://panorosys.com/products/taglibname/taglib"
                template="/WEB-INF/templates/clrp-template.xhtml">
```

Then you should use your implemented page twice in html as you expected. To do this, you can  create two divs horizontally and use this taglib on both divs.

```
                        <div class="box1">
                            <clrp:userlist />
                        </div>
                        <div class="box2">
                            <clrp:userlist />
                        </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please share the complete code. I am also facing the same issue.